# Carttrhob packages and price modifier inventory

Tags: cartthrob, packages

I'm having an issue trying to get the inventory value for products loaded into a package. As far as I can see I have all the correct set up done, I can add a package and products to the cart - and can checkout with the correct products.

I have given the item_options modifier a data-stock attribute so I can check against this using JS and display a message if the item is out of stock. This works on a regular product channel but for some reason the {sub:inventory} tag is spitting out a really long random string. Any ideas what may be going on? Below is my item_options block which is inside a {packages_packages} tag.

```
{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{entry_id}" row_id="{sub:row_id}"}
{if dynamic}
  <label class="control-label" for="{option_field}">{option_label}</label>
{input}
{if:else}
{if options_exist}
{if allow_selection}
  <label class="control-label" for="{option_field}">{option_label}</label>
    <div class="controls">
{select class="chosen-size-select"} 
{if option_first_row}
  <option selected value="">Please select a size</option>
{/if}
  <option {selected} value="{option_value}" data-stock="{sub:inventory}" data-option-price="{if option_price_numeric != 0}{option_price_numeric}{/if}">
  {option_name}{if option_price_numeric != 0} +{option_price_numeric}{/if}
</option>
{/select}
</div>
{/if}
{/if}
{/if}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
```

URL for the result is here: http://oyumoyu.com/shop/outfit/outfit-01